# Search Input with side button on Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

So i try to display and search bar with button on the right side of it but i keep geeting this view even though i have display it as flex and justify center, and even when i change it into row it still show up as image below

[image]

here is my code:

```
      return (
        <div className="p-2">
          <div className="text-left pl-4 pb-4 font-bold text-3xl">
            <h2>Detail SKU</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="p-2 justify-center mt-4 flex">
            <form
              onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
              }}
            >
              <Autocomplete
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                id="grouped-demo"
                options={options.sort(
                  (a, b, index) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter)
                )}
                groupBy={(option) => option.firstLetter}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
                sx={{ width: 300 }}
                renderInput={(params) => {
                  params.inputProps.onKeyDown = handleKeyDown;
                  return <TextField {...params} label="Search SKU" />;
                }}
                renderGroup={(params) => (
                  <li key={params.key}>
                    <GroupHeader>{params.group}</GroupHeader>
                    <GroupItems>{params.children}</GroupItems>
                  </li>
                )}
              />
              <Button variant="contained">Search</Button>
            </form>
          </div>
    
          <Box sx={{ width: "100%", typography: "body1" }}>
            <TabContext value={value} index={0} classes={{ root: useStyles.tab }}>
              <Box sx={{ borderColor: "divider", p: 0 }}>
                <TabList
                  index={0}
                  classes={{ root: useStyles.tab }}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  variant="scrollable"
                  scrollButtons="auto"
                  aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
                >
                  <Tab label="BOM" value="1" />
                  <Tab label="Routing" value="2" />
                  <Tab label="Depre" value="3" />
                  <Tab label="OMC" value="4" />
                </TabList>
              </Box>
              <TabPanel style={{ padding: 10 }} value="1">
                <div className="m-0 p-0" style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
                  <DataGrid {...data} components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }} />
                </div>
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel value="2">Routing</TabPanel>
              <TabPanel value="3">Depre</TabPanel>
              <TabPanel value="4">OMC</TabPanel>
            </TabContext>
          </Box>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

any help on it??, i've been figure it out but it seems dont help at all or where did do wrong here actually??

Comment: You should make a more [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing display classname flex

```
<div className="p-2 justify-center mt-4">
```